# SharePoint Online Page Viewer Web Part Folder Path - I've Tried Everything!

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, page-viewer-web-part, path, mapped-folder

I've been Googling for 4 hours and have tried every syntax I could find and nothing works.  I get errors or no reaction at all when clicking "test link".  I want to display my company's network folder in SPO.  Here are some of the paths I have tried, some of them were attempts at adding a path to a document instead of a folder:

- file://\byers.local\plea\FCB_Projects\FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- [https://\byers.local](https://%5Cbyers.local)\plea\FCB_Projects
- file://byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- file:///byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- file://///byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- file://\byers.local\plea\FCB_Projects
- f\byers.local\plea\FCB_Projects
- //byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- File:///I:/ byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x - EA - VOF Sacramento\Change Control Form.docx
- file://byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- \byerseng.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\SacByersEA\Shared Documents\Anatomy of a segment name.docx
- I:\FCE0100x - EA - VOF Sacramento\Change Control Form.docx
- I:\FCE0100x - EA - VOF Sacramento
- file://\byers.local\plea\FCB_Projects
- \byers.local\plea\FCB_PR~1\FCE0100x - EA - VOF Sacramento
- \byers.local\plea\FCB_PR~1\
- file://byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/FCE0100x%20-%20EA%20-%20VOF%20Sacramento
- folder://byers.local\plea\FCB_Projects
- \byers.local\plea\FCB_PR~1\
- file://byers.local/plea/FCB_Projects/180518%20SACLT-278697A.UG.PDF

Answer (score 0):

The folder path like below and select "Folder" in page viewer web part settings.

```
File:\\sp2013\Folder1
```

[image]

Comment: I wish that did work but sadly, no